# Is doing REST with Django different than MVC?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, rest

I am building my first web app with jQuery/CSS3/HTML in the front end that would GET/POST data from a backend implemented in DJANGO.

For this, I would like to build entities in DJANGO that are ReSTified. The DJANGO site https://www.djangoproject.com/ talks mostly about DJANGO MVC. I dont think I want MVC. Am I thinking right? If so how would I get DJango do ReST for me?

Moreover what style of architecture is better? MVC or ReST?

Can you please advise?

Regards,
Manav

Answer (score 5):

These are completely orthogonal concepts.

Django is built on the MVC pattern (in fact a variant of that, better referred to as MTV). That simply refers to how the application is structured - in Django's case, with models, views and templates. If you're using Django, you can't get away from that.

REST is a pattern for how an application interacts with its caller - ie by using HTTP verbs and serving up (usually) JSON. You can't "build an application in REST", but you can write a REST application using any structure you like, including MVC.

Comment: Hey thanks for that answer. What I am basically looking at is an effective faster way of building an RIA.

If I use the DJango MVC, I will have to wait till I figure out DJango, get the views up.

However if I go with the ReST architecture, I can kinda outsource the UI development with placeholders for ReSTful calls while I can focus on the backend.

If I stick to MVC, I believe I cant achieve the speed I want especially when I am new to Django. 

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Django itself is an MVC framework. However, there are apps available that will allow you to create an API for your models.

I believe that the most common ones are [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) and [django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home)